# AJAX dont work on Druple

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Have a JS script

```
function saveToDatabase(editableObj,column,id) 
        $(editableObj).css("background","#FFF url(loaderIcon.gif) no-repeat right");
        $.ajax({
            url: "sites/default/files/php/user/SQLupd.php",
            type: "POST",
            data:'column='+column+'&editval='+editableObj.innerHTML+'&id='+id,
            success: function(data){
                alert('succ');
                $(editableObj).css("background","#FDFDFD");
            }        
       });
    }
```

And PHP

```
<?php
$query = \Drupal::database()->update('1cdata')
->condition('code', '1')
->fields([
'name' => 'name'])
->execute();
?>
```

But it never even

```
alert('succ');
```

What can be a problem? 
JQuery is enabled and path is correct.

Comment: Did you add an error handler to see what the issue is?

Comment: What does the AJAX call return? Have you inspected it using the network tools of your browser?

Comment: I forgot about chrome debugg tool. Now it work correct. Thx you too.